# Pircbot getting gettin text from txt file into command

Tags: java, readfile

Hello i'm working on a Irc Bot for Twich and i wanna add a command that gets text from a txt file and uses it in a command

EX: user type's "!song" in chat -> bot get the song title from a txt file and say's in chat the Song title.

i got the part working that gets the data from the txt file but i cant get that data in the command.

```
import org.jibble.pircbot.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class MprovBot extends PircBot 
{

// Get song title from Txt file
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileReader file = new FileReader ("song.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    String song = "";
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null){
        song += line;
        line = reader.readLine();
    } 

    System.out.println(song);
}

// IRC Commands_
public MprovBot() {
    this.setName("MprovBot");
}

public void onMessage(String channel, String sender,
    String login, String hostname, String message) {
    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!test")) {
        sendMessage (channel, "Test Done");
    }

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!Command")) {
        sendMessage (channel, "This are the commands you can do.");
    }

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!song")){
        sendMessage (channel, song);
    }
    }
    }
```

when i try to compile the code i get this

```
MprovBot.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
   sendMessage (channel, song);
                         ^
symbol:   variable song
location: class MprovBot
1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `song` is not defined in the `onMessage()` method. So the compiler can't find the variable. What you have to do is to change the main method to a normal method with a return type, and call this method on receiving the `!song` command.

```
public class MprovBot extends PircBot {

    // Get song title from Txt file AND return it!
    public String getSong() throws Exception {
        FileReader file = new FileReader ("song.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

        String song = "";
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null){
            song += line;
            line = reader.readLine();
        } 

        return song;
    }

    // IRC Commands_
    public MprovBot() {
        this.setName("MprovBot");
    }

    public void onMessage(String channel, String sender,
        String login, String hostname, String message) {
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!test")) {
            sendMessage (channel, "Test Done");
        }

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!Command")) {
            sendMessage (channel, "This are the commands you can do.");
        }

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!song")){
            String song = "";
            try {
                song = getSong();
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            sendMessage (channel, song);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nicolai edited the answer, there was an error because of the `try`

Comment: i did that and it gives me a new error :

    MprovBot.java:83: error: ';' expected
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() }
                                                      ^
    1 error

so i did that and try to complile again and i get the old same error that "Variable song" is undefined

Comment: ok i did that but now is the String song in the sendMessage (channle, song); a unknown variable :S

Comment: @Nicolai Did you see the `String song = "";` before the `try`?